# SQL Trigger after INSERT

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to SQL triggers and I am trying to create a trigger on INSERT statement and am having some trouble.

GOAL:

I am importing data from an application called UPS Worldship that is just inserting 4 rows of data (TxnID, SalesOrderLineRefListID, SalesOrderLineDesc, SalesOrderLineRate) into my SQL server from designated fields.  Upon this INSERT I am hoping to build a trigger that will take the values from the most recent insert for columns TxnID and SalesOrderLineRefListID and place that data into a new insert statement that will affect a different table.

The issue here is the TxnID and SalesOrderLineRefListID must match that of a record in a different table or the insert will fail.

Is there a way to create a trigger that upon the insert of a row, to automatically place that data into a new INSERT statement affecting another table?

For example:

The data being received is coming in as INSERT INTO dbo.UPS_Shipment_History (TxnID, SalesOrderLineRefListID, SalesOrderLineDesc, SalesOrderLineRate) VALUES (123456, 123456, Tracking, 1.0)

It displays as the below:

[image: SQL server image reference]

However:

This is a linked server connection.

To pull data from the table I am looking to INSERT INTO, I am using SELECT from QRemote...SalesOrderLine which pulls the data from that table.  To INSERT to it, its very similar and I am using INSERT INTO QRemote...SalesOrderLine (TxnID, SalesOrderLineRefListID, SalesOrderLineDesc, SalesOrderLineRate) VALUES (123456, 123456, Tracking, 1.0) which works fine.

I guess my question is:

Is it possible to write a trigger that will append the new data on INSERT into the SQL statement above automatically?

Comment: Please do not use tags that do not apply to your question. I removed the database tags as it is unclear which one you are actually using. Please add the tag of *only* the database you are actually using

Comment: First a couple of questions...Are TxnID and SalesOrderLineRefListID actual values you are submitting?  or are they identity field values?  If they are known values, make a second insert and submit your statements as a single transaction.  If they are server incremented values - If you have the permissions you can create the trigger on the tables on the linked server.  If not, which is more like the cause of this question in the first place, you can write a procedure that will execute your original insert and generate an output for each value you need to insert using the second statement.

Comment: Triggers are **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a insert trigger for the table and get values from 'Inserted' in trigger

[more on sql trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql)

> ```
> CREATE TRIGGER ShipmentTrigger ON UPS_Shipment_History
> FOR INSERT
> AS
> INSERT INTO yourDifferenttable (
>   TxnID
>   ,SalesOrderLineRefListID
>   )
> SELECT TxnID
>   ,SalesOrderLineRefListID
> FROM inserted
> GO
> ```